# How to open HTML pages stored in CouchDB over the browser?

Tags: html, browser, couchdb

I am trying to view an HTML page that's saved as an attachment over the browser.  When I navigate to the link, I get a prompt asking me to download the file.  I want to open it directly in the browser.  How do I do this?

Here's how I saved it:

```
 curl -vX PUT http://localhost:5984/database/app/index.html -d index.html -H "Content-Type: application/html"
```

Comment: the correct content type is text/html

Comment: @neuhaus  Thanks, that was a silly error.

Comment: @neuhaus  After setting the correct content type, the file opens in the browser but doesn't dislay any content -- it just shows the name of the file.  In the console it says that the content type isn't declared, even though I declared it in a meta tag.

Comment: did you check the source of the web page in the browser? Also try downloading the page with "curl -i" and check what Content-Type is set.

Comment: @neuhaus  this is the response I get:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
ETag: "XH9NQBPXz9K9v/EcWKXD/A=="
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 12:42:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 12
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Accept-Ranges: none`

Comment: @neuhaus  I changed my command to `curl -vX PUT 'http://localhost:5984/database/app/index.html' -d@index.html` and now it works

Comment: @neuhaus  Do you know if I can upload an entire directory to CouchDB using curl, or do I have to upload each file individually?